# matching tuples in pandas and data processing

Tags: python, csv, pandas

The following is a simplified blob of my dataframe. I want to process

[first.csv](https://gist.github.com/ecenm/97248a1d1f6f301d662c6f238b6168df)

```
,No.,Time,Source,Destination,Protocol,Length,Info,src_dst_pair
325778,112.305107,02:e0,Broadcast,ARP,64,Who has 253.244.230.77?  Tell 253.244.230.67,"('02:e0', 'Broadcast')"
801130,261.868118,02:e0,Broadcast,ARP,64,Who has 253.244.230.156?  Tell 253.244.230.67,"('02:e0', 'Broadcast')"
700094,222.055094,02:e0,Broadcast,ARP,60,Who has 253.244.230.77?  Tell 253.244.230.156,"('02:e0', 'Broadcast')"
766542,766543,247.796156,100.118.138.150,41.177.26.176,TCP,66,32222 > http [SYN] Seq=0,"('100.118.138.150', '41.177.26.176')"
767405,248.073313,100.118.138.150,41.177.26.176,TCP,64,32222 > http [ACK] Seq=1,"('100.118.138.150', '41.177.26.176')"
767466,248.083268,100.118.138.150,41.177.26.176,HTTP,380,Continuation [Packet capture],"('100.118.138.150', '41.177.26.176')"
```

I have all the unique elements of the (last element) src_dst_pair

```
uniq_src_dst_pair = numpy.unique(data.src_dst_pair.ravel())
[('02:e0', 'Broadcast') ('100.118.138.150', '41.177.26.176')]
```

How can I do the following in pandas

for each element in uniq_src_dst_pair, check against the df.src_dst_pair. If it matches, add df.Length and store it in a separate column

**my expected result is**

```
('02:e0', 'Broadcast') : 188
('100.118.138.150', '41.177.26.176') : 510
```

How can  I do this?

**Below is my try**

```
import pandas
import numpy


data = pandas.read_csv('first.csv')
print data

uniq_src_dst_pair = numpy.unique(data.src_dst_pair.ravel())
print uniq_src_dst_pair
print len(uniq_src_dst_pair)

# following is hardcoded, but need to be more general for the above list
match1 = data[data.src_dst_pair == "('02:e0:ed:0a:fb:5f', 'Broadcast')"] # doesn't work
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you're trying to get the total number of bytes transmitted through each connection (where a connection is identified by source and destination), right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your csv file is messed up. You shouldn't have the first comma in the header, and you have an extra field in your 4th non-header row. Fixing that, you could use:

```
In [6]: data.groupby('src_dst_pair').Length.sum()
Out[6]: 
src_dst_pair
('02:e0', 'Broadcast')                  188
('100.118.138.150', '41.177.26.176')    510
Name: Length, dtype: int64
```

However, your final field, 'src_dst_pair' is superfluous if this is what you wanted to accomplish because you can simply do something like the following:

```
In [8]: data.groupby(['Source','Destination']).Length.sum()
Out[8]: 
Source           Destination  
02:e0            Broadcast        188
100.118.138.150  41.177.26.176    510
Name: Length, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks, the src_data_pair has some other objectives. I didn't show here for code simplicity. But appreciate your insights.